# Оптимизация запроса с помощью анализа плана выполнения запросов MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Просмотрел много видео, прочитал лекции, но никак не могу оптимизировать запрос посредством анализа плана выполнения запросов. Например, есть Nested Loops, знаю, что его можно увидеть в случае соединение с таблицей по атрибуту, в которой есть дубли значения по которому мы соединяемся. Подумал использовать хинты, так сказать, принудить SQL Server поменять свое решение по построению плана запроса, а потом наткнулся на лекцию Дениса Резника, в которой он говорит, что хинты лучше не использовать вообще, т.к. по началу, возможно, будет все хорошо, а потом, с увеличением данных, этот хинт может сыграть плохую шутку. Вообщем, план запросов читать могу, а вот оптимизировать запрос глядя на этот план не получается. Что можете посоветовать? Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы.

Comment: Оптимизируют конкретные запросы, у которых есть проблема, а не запросы вообще. С чего вы взяли, что Nested Loop - это что-то плохое? С хинтами та же история.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin я же написал, что посмотрел лекцию Дениса Резника, который рассказал почему не стоит использовать хинты. А у вас есть пример проблемного запроса? Как вы определяете проблемный запрос?

Comment: [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/dta/tutorial-database-engine-tuning-advisor?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хинты для оптимизации - это недоработка БД, их стоит применять, если ты совсем никак не можешь повлиять на БД.

Для понимания планов запросов есть шикарная книга: [SQL Server Execution Plans](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/books/sql-server-execution-plans-third-edition-by-grant-fritchey/)(сейчас актуально третье издание).

Ещё посмотри выступления Сергея Олонцева. Резника продолжай смотреть - крутой тип.

Сейчас начни с вышеупомянутой книги(1-3 глава) и начинай экспериментировать.

Ещё порекомендую почитать [Дмитрия Короткевича](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430259620), [тут](https://russianblogs.com/article/91801617780/) есть перевод нескольких глав, почитай про индексы/статистику.

Для оптимизации нужно понимать подкапотные вещи, в этом ещё знание основ программирования помогает, такие как алгоритмы и структуры данных. Нужно представлять дерево индекса и поиск по нему, что такое вложенные циклы, что такое хэш-таблица.. С этим помогает справиться книга [Грокаем алгоритмы](https://www.ozon.ru/product/grokaem-algoritmy-illyustrirovannoe-posobie-dlya-programmistov-i-lyubopytstvuyushchih-139296295/?sh=dBAUn5EJTw).

Comment: Огромное спасибо за информацию Vitaliy Zlobin. Та же проблема. Теорию знаю, читаю, но на практике многодневное хождение вокруг запроса... а он ещё медленнее. Спасибо.